# mongodb unknown top level operator: $function nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to extract only those collections which are not selected by user.
Here is my code.

```
return await Campaign.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from:"influncer_campaign_mapping",
                        localField: "campaignId",
                        foreignField:"campaignId",
                        as: "icmapping"
                    }
                },
                {$unwind:"$icmapping"},
                {
                  $match: {$function:{
                    body: function(icmapping) {
                        if(icmapping != null || icmapping != undefined){
                            return {"icmapping.userId":{$ne:"ccdc7d1a-9cdb-4768-b8c1-0446e35576fb"}}
                        }else{ return null}
                        
                     },
                     args: [ "$icmapping" ],
                     lang: "js"

                  }
                }
            }
        ])
```

My mapping table

```
{
        influncerCampaignMappingId: { type: String, require: true },
        userId: { type: String, require: true },
        campaignId: { type: String, require: true },
        // isSelected: { type: Boolean, require: true, default: true },
        isDeleted: { type: Boolean, require: true },
        deletedDate: { type: Date, require: true },
    },
```

and here is campaign table where i am storing the list of campaign.

```
 {
        campaignId: { type: String, require: true },
        name: { type: String, require: true },
        image: { type: String, require: true },
        serviceName: { type: String, require: true },
        description: { type: String, require: true },
        categoryId: [{ type: String }],
        keywords: [{ type: String }]
}
```

Actually I am considering campaignId from campaign table and userId from user table and insert it into mapping table.
Now the goal is to achieve only those collections(list) which is not selected previously by user,
so that they can see only those campaign(list) which they not selected yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, hope it helps

```
return await Campaign.aggregate([{
                $lookup: {
                    from: "influncer_campaign_mapping",
                    localField: "campaignId",
                    foreignField: "campaignId",
                    as: "icmapping"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$icmapping"
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $and:
    
                        [{
                            $ne: ["icmapping.userId", "ccdc7d1a-9cdb-4768-b8c1-0446e35576fb"],
                            $ne: ["icmapping.userId", null]
                        }]
                }
            }
        ])
```

Comment: it is giving me an empty array(tried earlier), but i want those also for which mapping is not created.